# How to activate wifi on new laptop

Tags: realtek

I've just installed Ubuntu studio 21.10 on a new Asus laptop. Its now dual Boot with W10. Wifi works as expected in W10 but not in ubuntu. Adapter is a Realtek RTL8821CE. Is shows up when I do sudo lspci but beyond that I'm lost in Terminal. Any help to get the correct drivers installed would be greatly appreciated

```
benm@Bens-asus:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
        DeviceName: WLAN
        Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3040]
        Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
benm@Bens-asus:~$ sudo dmesg | grep 8821
[sudo] password for benm: 
[    3.899773] rtw_8821ce 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    3.901991] rtw_8821ce 0000:03:00.0: Firmware version 24.8.0, H2C version 12
[    3.924396] rtw_8821ce 0000:03:00.0: rfe 4 isn't supported
[    3.924819] rtw_8821ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
[    3.924824] rtw_8821ce 0000:03:00.0: failed to setup chip information
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep 8821`

Comment: I've pasted it in but it has changed the layout a bit

Comment: Kernel 5.14 and above seem to address this issue/bug.

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r rtw88_8821ce` and: `sudo modprobe rtw88_pci disable_aspm=1` and then: `sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce` Is there any improvement? Reference: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210779

Comment: I have entered the code but it seemed to have no effect

Comment: benm@Bens-asus:~$ sudo modprobe -r rtw88_8821ce
[sudo] password for benm: 
benm@Bens-asus:~$ sudo modprobe rtw88_pci disable_aspm=1
benm@Bens-asus:~$ sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce
benm@Bens-asus:~$ ^C
benm@Bens-asus:~$

Comment: nothing seemed to happen in terminal and no change to the wifi

Comment: I am currently updating to Kernal 5.14. I think.

Comment: i've just gone through the update process but it seems i'm only at 5.13!

Comment: Did you reboot? What does this tell us? `uname -r`

Comment: yes, rebooted.    5.13.0-27-lowlatency

Comment: i tried following this   https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-or-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-5-14-on-debian-11-bullseye/#ftoc-heading-8   but get to a stage where it says   E: Type ‘sudo’ is not known on line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: No. Do not follow a Debian guide. I have no doubt that it doesn't work. Please revert all changes.

Comment: maybe i should reinstall. I tried your guide and i still get the message about the source list. I have no idea how to revert the changes

Comment: You could reinstall in 15 minutes or meet me in chat and undo all of the incorrect steps, maybe, in a couple of hours. Which do you prefer?

Comment: thank you, i think i'll reinstall in the morning. i have no work to back up or anything so a nice clean install might be best. I will let you know how it goes. i love working with ubuntu, this is third laptop i've had ubuntu on but every time the wifi has been an problem. i don't really understand why such a fundamental thing is such an issue

Comment: I will propose what I believe to be a *proper* working solution for the wifi a bit later. See you tomorrow.

Comment: yes it worked! I reinstalled then did the steps you suggested and it worked! Thank you

Comment: In fact now that I've got working wifi, dropbox and scrcpy installed I hope I never have to go near the terminal again!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the well-known bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210779

> rtw88_8821ce doesn't work [1]  can't connect  [2]

Let’s blacklist the native driver:

```
sudo -i
echo “blacklist rtw88_8821ce”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Next, with a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms build-essential bc linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Reboot, disable Secure Boot and your wireless should be working.

Answer (score 1):

This guide should work:

Secure boot must be deactivated.

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)

> git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

> cd rtl8821ce

> chmod +x dkms-install.sh

> chmod +x dkms-remove.sh

> sudo ./dkms-install.sh

For deinstallation:

> sudo ./dkms-remove.sh

Or you can try this:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)

> wget [https://launchpad.net/~canonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/rtl8821ce/+files/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425-0ubuntu1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/rtl8821ce/+files/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425-0ubuntu1_all.deb)

> sudo dpkg -i *.deb

For further instructions look here:

https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wlan-modul-nicht-aktieviert-unter-ubuntu-18-04/#post-8985121

Comment: You probably also need to blacklist the native driver.